# LAMP With NodeJS and Socket IO

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I developed web site with LAMP, where I need users to chat with each other, make group chat or PM. I googled the solution and found that the best way to create chat/messaging application is NodeJS & SocketIO. I wrote small chat client/server application with Node and Socket. But I have a problem, Node JS runs on another port, because has own server and does not need apache, but my goal is to integrate Chat application with my web site, in short, i want my chat to run with apache 80 port (inside www root folder).

I used this tutorial on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ

Comment: Have you taken a look at Apache's [mode_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) module?  You could proxy the requests from Apache to the Node server.

Comment: I ll check it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run Nodejs on another port locally and use Apaches Proxy-Module to pass request to nodejs.

How-to: http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to expose one port to the outside for both node and Apache, you're better off using something like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) in front and then set up HAProxy to proxy to node or Apache (depending on the requested path for example). This is more efficient because HAProxy is event-driven and does not use one worker thread/process per connection like Apache's `mod_proxy` modules generally would.